# C++ defined long long but the output is limited

Tags: c++, precision, long-integer

I am currently learning C++, so I am a beginner. I thought I'd make a small program to generate the Bessel polynomial terms. This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

// x!
long long fact(const long long &x)
{
  long long z {1};
  for (long long i=1; i<=x; ++i)
    z *= i;
  return z;
}

// 2^n
long long pwr2(const int &n)
{
  long long z {1};
  for (long long i=0; i<n; ++i)
    z *= 2;
  return (n == 0 ? 1 : z);
}

// Bessel coefficients
long long bessel(long long *a, const long long &N)
{
  for (long long i=0; i<=N; ++i)
    a[i] = fact(N + i) / (pwr2(i) * fact(N - i) * fact(i));
  return *a;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "N = ";
  long long N;
  std::cin >> N;

  long long *a {new long long[N + 1]};
  *a = bessel(a, N);

  for (long long i=0; i<=N; ++i)
    std::cout << a[i] << ( i<N ? " " : "\n");

  delete a;
  a = nullptr;

  return 0;
}
```

N=10 seems to be the limit. `sizeof(long long)` shows 8 (archlinux x64). fact(20) > (2^64)-1, so I'm stuck, even with long long. Is there a way to circumvent this limit?

The code, as you see it, is after I got desperate and modified all int to long long. I even added "ll" to all the numbers, there's no effect. I even removed the main parenthesis from the denominator and arranged the terms so that they divide, progressively, to somehow balance themselves, e.g.:
`fact(N+i)/fact(N-i)/fact(i)/pwr2(i)`, also no effect.

Comment: can you use an `unsigned long long`?

Comment: If that's the limit, that's the limit. If you want bigger numbers, you'll have to use a library that handles big integers (or, design such a library yourself). These are nowhere near as fast as using real long longs though.

Comment: By the way, you can rewrite pwr2 as `long long pwr2(long long n) {return 1<<n;}`

Comment: I know with some gcc versions there is __attribute__(mode(TI))" which can get you a 128 but int in some platforms. But that is a very playform dependent way to do it

Comment: @MrLister I forgot about that trick. I know about it mathematically, but it didn't occur to me that can be done. I can only suppose it's much faster than multiplication, probably one cycle long?

Comment: @AlexZywicki I don't know how that is used, at least not yet, but it raises a question: if I implement it, would the executable be able to run on other computers? This program will be part of a bigger one, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think you can rewrite the complicated factorial division so each term is just a multiple of the last, without factorials. (I'm not certain, though. My maths skills are low right now because wine.) Avoiding the factorials can help keep overflow at bay.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, that was my plan B. I mentioned it in banguru's reply. (edit: though that may have some floating point trouble, but, it's a valid plan B :-) )

Comment: @a-concerned-citizen I understand the concern in using that feature, it is an atrributbe that can be applied to a type using gcc. It is NOT a platform independent solution, which is why I suggested as a comment rather than an answer. It would allow you to do what you need but may not be the best or most correct solution to your problem.

Comment: @AlexZywicki Well, even so, I am still at numerical limits' mercy, since even wwith the recursion formula, the a[0] term is (2*N)!/N!, which means for N=10, a[0]/(2**64-1)<1, but for N=11 it's >1. I might have to wait a bit and learn how to use external libraries like the one banguru suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want to with native types as they are limited by bit sizes.
However you can use some libraries to accomplish those ([This is one such example)](https://gmplib.org/) if you really need it (But as per your question , you are just learning c++ so I guess you dont need those)

Comment: I see. I still have an alternative, which is by using a recursive formula, a[n]/a[n-1], which is much better, but I wanted to try it out this way. Fortunately, this problem happened and now I am one answer wiser. :-) Unfortunately, I can't vote up. Thanl you for the answer, though.